# Splunk: How to check the logfile size of specific logfiles?

Tags: splunk

I want to check the size of specific logfiles in Splunk. I found this query:

```
index=foo* | bin span=1d _time | stats sum(eval(len(_raw))) as TotalSize by _time
```

I am not completely sure what this query tells me? Is TotalSite the number of bytes?

If no, what would be a way to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query provides the size in bytes of all of the indexes with names starting with "foo" (in total).  One total is given for each day with the number of days determined by the time window selected in the UI.